# HTML5 Canvas: Using constructor functions to create complex Canvas shapes

Tags: javascript, canvas, constructor, html5-canvas

I'm currently working on a HTML5 Canvas project (I wrote a separate question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67259351/callback-function-inside-if-statement-not-working)). I think one of the solutions to the problems I am facing would be to create a reference for the path (saved as an object), and use the method `ispointinpath` to check if my mouse position is within the path or not – if its not, it resets the game.

I took a stab at creating a constructor function for a complex path shape. Here's what the complex shape looks like as raw code:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

// returning a drawing context to a variable 'c'
// allows you to draw 2d elements
var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

  canvas.width = 1000;
  canvas.height = 700;
  canvas.style.width = 1000;
  canvas.style.height = 700;
  
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(350, 650); //start
        c.lineTo(350, 200);
        c.lineTo(900, 200);
        c.lineTo(900, 250);
        c.lineTo(700, 250);
        c.lineTo(600, 250);
        c.lineTo(600, 650);
        c.fillStyle = "#C1EEFF";
        c.fill();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Here's what it looks like as a constructor function that I tried to make:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

// returning a drawing context to a variable 'c'
// allows you to draw 2d elements
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = 1000;
  canvas.height = 700;
  canvas.style.width = 1000;
  canvas.style.height = 700;
  

var points = [(350, 200), (900, 200), (900, 250), (700, 250), (600, 250), (600, 650)];

function Path(startX, startY, array, color){
      c.beginPath();
      c.moveTo(startX, startY);

      // For however many element pairs in the array, create a lineTo statement
      for(i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        c.lineTo(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
      }
  
      c.fillStyle = color;
      c.fill();
}

var blue = new Path(350, 200, points, '#C1EEFF');
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

It doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone know why that is? Also, what would be the best syntax for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The `this` in the `Path` function is not a canvas context. You can use the global variable `c` instead: `c.beginPath();` etc,

Comment: The question you linked is closed, most people will not be able to see it, best to not start a question with a reference to another question, just focus on one issue at a time

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use an object with position x, y

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

// returning a drawing context to a variable 'c'
// allows you to draw 2d elements
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 700;
canvas.style.width = 1000;
canvas.style.height = 700;

var points = [
  { x: 350, y: 200 },
  { x: 900, y: 200 },
  { x: 900, y: 250 },
  { x: 700, y: 250 },
  { x: 600, y: 250 },
  { x: 600, y: 650 }
];

function Path(startX, startY, array, color) {
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(startX, startY);
  // For however many element pairs in the array, create a lineTo statement
  for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    c.lineTo(array[i].x, array[i].y);
  }
  c.fillStyle = color;
  c.fill();
}

var blue = new Path(350, 200, points, "#C1EEFF");
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you explain why is that better?

Comment: It may be preference but I also prefer using an object when dealing with coordinates. Having the x and y to reference when accessing the values makes things more understandable to me and others who may read your code.

Comment: I see what you're saying but I don't think this will work for what I am trying to do. I'm going to be creating paths of different shapes. I feel like this would be good if you're trying to make the same type of shape in different places.

Answer (score 0):

First issue is your points array:
`var points = [(350, 200), (900, 200),...`
that is not a correct bi-dimensional array, maybe you meant:
`var points = [[350, 200], [900, 200],...`

also in your code `Path` is a function not a class, not sure why you doing `new Path(...)`
maybe you got that mixed with `new Path2D()` but that is completely different...
Look at the parameters for isPointInPath:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath#syntax

Here is a working example

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 700;

// Function to generate a Path2D object
function Path(array) {
  let path = new Path2D();
  path.moveTo(array[0][0], array[0][1]); 
  for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    path.lineTo(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
  }
  path.lineTo(array[0][0], array[0][1]);
  return path
}

//Create the paths
var big = [[350,200], [900,200], [900,250], [700,250], [600,250], [600,650], [350,650]];
var blue = Path(big);

var triangle = [[25,10], [70,10], [90,85]];
var red = Path(triangle);

// Draw all the paths
c.beginPath()
c.fillStyle = "blue";
c.fill(blue);

c.beginPath()
c.fillStyle = "red";
c.fill(red);

// use isPointInPath
console.log(c.isPointInPath(blue, 10, 10))
console.log(c.isPointInPath(blue, 351,201))
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

---

Now on the now closed question my suggestion to using `isPointInPath` is to improve scalability, you had a bunch of hard coded if statement, that approach for more complex polygons just would not do... BUT you still have the problem in your game how to handle the transition between levels, that was the root problem on that question.

Comment: What's the purpose of the color parameter? I don't see it used anywhere else in the code

Comment: No use for that color parameter, just copy/paste leftover from your code ... had to step away and did not have time to polish my answer... doing it now

Comment: @SolangeWright I removed the unused color param & added some more details

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to access your array coordinates using this syntax array[i][0], array[i][1] however your array is NOT an array of arrays it is an array of parenthesis. I don’t have time to play with it but try making it an array of arrays so you can then access element [0] and [1].

[[350, 200], [400, 250]] etc

EDIT:
I am providing an ES6 class to create your maps. This is just another option on top of the others provided here.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 700;
 
let points = [[300, 400], [400, 400], [400, 350], [400, 250], [700, 250], [700, 150], [750, 150], [750, 50], [775, 50], [775, 175], [725, 175], [725, 400], [500, 400], [500, 500], [500, 650], [300, 650] ];
let points2 = [[750, 50], [775, 50], [775, 100], [750, 100]];

class Map {
  constructor(start_x, start_y, arr, c) {
    this.start_x = start_x;
    this.start_y = start_y;
    this.arr = arr;
    this.color = c;
  }
  draw() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(this.start_x, this.start_y); //start
    this.arr.forEach(point => c.lineTo(point[0], point[1]));
    c.fillStyle = this.color;
    c.fill();
    c.closePath(); 
  }
}
let map1 = new Map(300, 650, points, 'blue');
let map1Finish = new Map(750, 100, points2, 'red');
map1.draw();
map1Finish.draw();
```