# How to check if mouse position is inside HTML5 Canvas path?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm new to HTML5 Canvas and Javascript. I'm currently working on a HTML5 Canvas project (I wrote a separate question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67259351/callback-function-inside-if-statement-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272338/html5-canvas-using-constructor-functions-to-create-complex-canvas-shapes)).

The logic of the game is pretty simple: track the mouse position and if the mouse position exits the blue region, the game resets. The user starts on level 1 (`function firstLevel`). If their mouse position enters the red box region, they advance onto the next level (`return secondLevel()`). I did this previously by a hefty list of `if` statements that compared the mouse's x and y coordinates.

I've corrected the code to create a global constructor function I can reference in each of the level functions:

```js
function Path(array, color) {
  let path = new Path2D();
  path.moveTo(array[0][0], array[0][1]); 
  for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    path.lineTo(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
  }
  path.lineTo(array[0][0], array[0][1]);
  return path;
}
```

And its referenced in the level functions as such:

```js
    // In the individual levels, put code that describes the shapes locally
    var big = [[350,200], [900,200], [900,250], [700,250], [600,250], [600,650], [350,650]];
    var blue = Path(big);

    var small = [[900,200], [900,250], [850,250], [850, 200], [900, 200]];
    var red = Path(small);

      // 2. create cursor
      c.beginPath();
      c.rect(mouseX, mouseY, mouseWidth, mouseHeight);
      c.fillStyle = "#928C6F";
      c.fill();

    // Local code that draws shapes:
    c.beginPath()
    c.fillStyle = '#C1EEFF';
    c.fill(blue);

    c.beginPath()
    c.fillStyle = "#FF4000";
    c.fill(red);
```

I want to know how can I check for the mouse position so it can run those conditional statements using the `isPointInPath` method? I now have a reference (refs. `blue` and `red`) for the Canvas shape, so I'm hoping there's a way I can check if the mouse's x and y position is a point that is inside the shape/path.

**Link to my project:** https://github.uconn.edu/pages/ssw19002/dmd-3475/final-project/maze-page-1.html

**Source code:** https://github.uconn.edu/ssw19002/dmd-3475/tree/master/final-project

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`MouseEvent.offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) and [`MouseEvent.offsetY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) properties of a mouse event such as [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event).  (You would need to add an event listener for mouse events to the canvas element of course.)

Then use the `x` and `y` offset values obtained to call [`isPointInPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) like

```
ctx.isPointInPath(path, x, y)
```

where `path` is a return value from `function Path`.

While MDN lists the offset properties as "experimental" they seem to have been around since IE9 at least.